# Implement custom logging in Loopback 4

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, winston, bunyan

Can Winston, Pino or Bunyan be used for logging in Loopback4? If so, what would be the basic steps to implement them in Loopback4?

I was able to make Winston work using Express while viewing this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-winston-to-log-node-js-applications

There are Loopback modules for Winston and Brunyan. However, I get the impression (since last updates are greater than 10 months old) they must be for older versions of Loopback (since v4 came out in Oct 18')?

Winston - https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-winston

Brunyan - https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-component-bunyan

Answer (score 4):

It bothered me a bit that, if one of my routes threw an exception, the output could only be logged to stderr. So I did the following to fix this and use Winston for logging instead, while still being fully agnostic to the underlying logging system that is actually used.

Assume that in one of my controllers I have the following REST endpoint:

```js
@post('/myendpoint')
async handleEndpoint(): Promise<void> {
  throw new Error('I am an error!');
}
```

To now add the custom logger, I created a new service for it and bound the Winston variant of it to my application.

**src/services/logger.service.ts** (the abstract logger service and a concrete implementation of it that uses Winston)

```
import winston from 'winston';

export interface LoggerService {
  logger: object;
}

export class WinstonLoggerService implements LoggerService {
  logger: winston.Logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.timestamp(),
      winston.format.json(),
    ),
    transports: [
      new winston.transports.Console({
        format: winston.format.combine(
          winston.format.colorize(),
          winston.format.printf(info => {
            return `[${info.timestamp}]  ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
          }),
        ),
      }),
    ],
  });
}
```

**src/keys.ts**

```
export namespace LoggerBindings {
  export const LOGGER = BindingKey.create<LoggerService>('services.logger');
}
```

**src/providers/log-error.provider.ts** (a Loopback 4 provider class where the logger class bound by the application is injected into and which can then use it)

```
import {Provider} from '@loopback/context';
import {LogError, Request} from '@loopback/rest';
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {LoggerBindings} from '../keys';
import {LoggerService} from '../services/logger.service';

export class LogErrorProvider implements Provider<LogError> {
  constructor(@inject(LoggerBindings.LOGGER) protected logger: LoggerService) {}

  value(): LogError {
    return (err, statusCode, req) => this.action(err, statusCode, req);
  }

  action(err: Error, statusCode: number, req: Request) {
    if (statusCode < 500) {
      return;
    }

    this.logger.logger.error(
      `HTTP ${statusCode} on ${req.method} ${req.url}: ${err.stack ?? err}`,
    );
  }
}
```

**src/application.ts** (bind statements go into the constructor)

```
import {WinstonLoggerService} from './services/logger.service';
import {LogErrorProvider} from './providers/log-error.provider';

this.bind(LoggerBindings.LOGGER).toClass(WinstonLoggerService);
this.bind(RestBindings.SequenceActions.LOG_ERROR).toProvider(LogErrorProvider);
```

The last line in the previous code block is the key here, because it makes sure to bind our custom provider for `LOG_ERROR`. Internally, Loopback 4 uses the `RejectProvider` defined in `@loopback/rest/src/providers/reject.provider.ts` to handle errors thrown in REST endpoints. Into this provider, `RestBindings.SequenceActions.LOG_ERROR` is injected, which is taken from `@loopback/rest/src/providers/log-error.provider.ts` by default and which we redefine here. This way, we don't need to rewrite the entire reject provider but just the tiny part of it that handles logging REST errors.

When the example route is now invoked, the following is shown on the console:

```
[2020-01-05T23:41:28.604Z]  error: HTTP 500 on POST /myendpoint: Error: I am an error!
    at [...long stacktrace...]
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly the solution I need, but I'm getting an error when trying to run it for this line in the log-error provider: 
   this.logger.logger.error(
The response is
   Property 'error' does not exist on type 'object'.
I know it's been an eternity since you posted this, but would greatly appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: @llhilton sorry this is a bit late, but for others that come across this, you have check what type the `logger` that is injected is - if it is type `winston.Logger` or `winston.WinstonLogger`, then all you need to do is call `this.logger.error`, due to the logger having that method.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to implement custom logging in `Loopback 4` and doing so should not be much different than `Express`.
I have experimented with `winston` and hence, would detail out the same but this should be achievable using `bunyan` as well.

To begin with, you can create a `utils` folder at the root of your project to keep your custom logger. An app scaffolded using LB4 CLI takes a typical structure and with `utils` folder, it would look like the following:

```
.
|
|-- public
|-- src  
|-- utils
|   |-- logger
|       |-- index.js  <-- custom logger can be defined here.
|-- node_modules
|-- index.js
|--
.
```

I am using the example 
as outlined in the [winston's github repo](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#usage) for defining the logger:

```
// utils/logger/index.js

const winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.json(),
    defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
    transports: [
        //
        // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log` 
        // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
        //
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
        new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
    ]
});

module.exports = logger;
```

You can now start using the logger by 'importing' it across your application. For `index.js` in the root folder, the `import` would look like:

```
// index.js

const logger = require('./utils/logger');
```

For the logger defined earlier, the following statement will log `I am logged.` to a file called `combined.log`:

```
logger.info('I am logged.');
```

This should get you started.

P.S. I am sure the answer(and the approach) can be improved and hence, very much open to any helpful suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. This only covers manually invoked lines correct? What if I wanted to log to file everything that goes on, requests, console, stderr, stdout?

Answer (score 0):

I followed @sigalor answer, but with one change in that I used the built-in Loopback logging library to do this. Instead of the `logger.service.ts`, I have an instantiation of a WinstonLogger in `application.ts`, which I created by following [this guide](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Logging.html#installation):

```js
import {LogErrorProvider} from './providers/log-error.provider';
import {format} from 'winston';
import {
  LoggingBindings,
  LoggingComponent,
  WINSTON_TRANSPORT,
  WinstonTransports,
} from '@loopback/logging';

export class VibratoRestV2Application extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
    //...
    // Configure logging
    this.configure(LoggingBindings.COMPONENT).to({
      enableFluent: false, // default to true
      enableHttpAccessLog: false, // default to true
    });
    this.configure(LoggingBindings.WINSTON_LOGGER).to({
      level: logConfig.logLevel ?? 'info',
      format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
      defaultMeta: {framework: 'Loopback'},
    });
    const fileTransport = new WinstonTransports.File({
      level: logConfig.logLevel ?? 'info',
      lazy: false,
      filename: logConfig.location ?? 'file.log',
      maxsize: 1000000, // 1MB
      maxFiles: 5,
      tailable: true,
      zippedArchive: true,
    });
    this.bind('logger.winston.transports.file')
      .to(fileTransport)
      .apply(extensionFor(WINSTON_TRANSPORT));
    this.component(LoggingComponent);

    // Log errors through provider
    this.bind(RestBindings.SequenceActions.LOG_ERROR) .toProvider(
      LogErrorProvider,
    );
}
```

Then, all you need is to configure his `log-error.provider.ts` which is where the real magic happens:

```js
import {Provider} from '@loopback/context';
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {LoggingBindings, WinstonLogger} from '@loopback/logging';
import {LogError, Request} from '@loopback/rest';
import {createLogger, Logger} from 'winston';

export class LogErrorProvider implements Provider<LogError> {
  constructor(
    @inject(LoggingBindings.WINSTON_LOGGER) protected logger: WinstonLogger,
  ) {createLogger()}

  value(): LogError {
    return (err, statusCode, req) => this.action(err, statusCode, req);
  }

  action(err: Error, statusCode: number, req: Request) {
    if (statusCode < 500) {
      return;
    }

    this.logger.error(
      `HTTP ${statusCode} on ${req.method} ${req.url}: ${err.stack ?? err}`,
    );
  }
}
```

You can then get both error logging as well as custom logging. You can also use the `@logInvocation` decorator which comes with the logging library in Loopback4, however this will only print logs when the application log level is `DEBUG` or higher - [docs are here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Logging.html#basic-use):

```js
import {logInvocation} from '@loopback/logging';

@logInvocation()
export class PingController {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi @Arcsector, I have tried to follow your guide, using the built-in Loopback logging library as well. The console transport works as I get my logs in the console. But the file transport doesn't work. Doesn't create log file.
Did you experience this at any point?

Comment: @osi_okorie What version of Loopback are you on? Are there any errors in the loopback console? What does your log statement look like - are you using `@logInvocation` or are you testing this in a method with `this.logger.info` or something like that? If you're only trying this with errors, also make sure it works with info/manual logging first then we can debug the `LogErrorProvider` implementing the LogError provider